# Differentiate wave speed, don't understand

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, differentiation

The speed $v$ of some wave is $ω/k$ and I want to differentiate this with respect to $k$. Apparently this equals:

$dv/dk = d(ω/k)/dk-ω/k^2$

But I don't understand why. Isn't this just saying "the derivative minus the derivative"? Should it not simply be:

$-ω/k^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your equation is slightly incorrect, should be:

$$\frac{dv}{dk} = \frac{1}{k}\frac{d\omega}{dk} - \frac{\omega}{k^2}$$

This is because $\omega = \omega(k)$, $\omega$ is a function of $k$, so you need to apply the chain rule to evaluate the derivative.

The [dispersion relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_relation) may also be a topic of interest.